# Equation involving sum of binomial coefficients.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> Solve for $x$ if $$\sum_{i=0}^{16} {16 \choose i} 5^i = x^8$$

Not sure what to do here. Should I somehow use the binomial theorem to manipulate this to solve for $x$, or is there another approach that's better.

Comment: Yes, recognizing that as the Binomial Theorem will make quick work of it.

Comment: Write out $(1+5)^{16}$ using the Binomial Theorem.

Answer (score 3):

$\displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^{16} {16 \choose i} 5^i = x^8$

or, $\displaystyle x^8 = \sum_{i=0}^{16} {16 \choose i} 5^i = (5+1)^{16} = 36^8$

or, $x^8 - 36^8 = 0$

or, $(x-36)(x+36)(x^2+36^2)(x^4+36^4) = 0$

Now you can find all the eight roots!

More specifically,the eight roots are the following:

$36 \left(\cos \frac{2 \pi k}{8} + i \sin \frac{2 \pi k}{8} \right)$ where 
$k = 0, \ldots, 7$

Comment: @Claude Leibovici Fixed... Thanks a lot.